# Can't deploy to iPhone(1st Generation) after updating from Xcode 4.1 to 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, objective-c, deployment, xcode4.2

After updating from 4.1 to 4.2.1, I was not able to deploy to my 1st generation iPhone. I received a message that a debugger for version 3.0 - 3.2 needs to be downloaded. I downloaded it.

After downloading the debugger, now Xcode displays the messages:

"Build succeeded" and "Finished  running....".

But the application doesn't even launch! 
There haven't been any code changes.
The only other change is that Xcode suggested I update the build settings to use the llvm 3.0 compiler (all I did was click OK).

Now It won't deploy to my first gen iPhone.! :C

It seems to deploy to my 4th generation iPod touch (iOS 5.01 (9A405)) without problem though.

Is there some kind of code change or setting change I need to make?
The last version of Xcode where I could deploy was 4.1 . After that I updated to 4.2.1

EDIT: I followed rckoenes advice below, and I added armv6 & armv7 to the architectures (and removed the variable that was already there). Now the application launches on my device, but almost immediately into the launch, the following error appears :

dyld: Symbol not found: __NSConcreteStackBlock
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/921C1E7F-449D-4EA1-AEAA-70A1AF60C351/ProjectX.app/ProjectX
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

I have tried the following:

under "Build Phases" for the targets, I have added libSystem.B.dylib under "Link Binary With Libraries".

But the error message still appears.

EDIT: Marking the library as optional in "Link Binary With Libraries" makes the error go away".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add the armv6 to you Architectures list: http://triplesoftware.nl/2011/12/running-ios-5-build-apps-on-the-orignal-iphone-ipod-touch-and-iphone-3g/

Comment: You will probably need to also remove the `armv7` key from the `Required device capabilities` in `<your-app>-Info.plist`

Comment: Thanks guys. Please see the updated post above. As now the application starts to launch but there is a new error which I haven't been able to solve.

Comment: @Paul.s Thanks Paul. My info.plist lists only the acceleromets and opengles1 as the required device capabilities.

Comment: The dyld is just a warning, but if you are using block the device needs to be running iOS4.

Comment: I'm not using a block. I haven't made any code changes after updating to Xcode 4.2.1, so I don't think this is a code problem. It isn't a warning. In my case the application crashes with the above error. =C

Comment: Found the solution - Had to weak link (make optional) the library under "Link Binary With Libraries" http://img.skitch.com/20100722-f65bkarx79gk8nye52ji834cbn.png  Thanks guys.